# 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python

```
import codecs
with open(filename+'.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for tweet in list_of_tweets:
        print(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
        f.write(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
```

Its showing

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import codecs
>   ----> 2 with open(filename+'.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>         3     for tweet in list_of_tweets:
>         4         print(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
>         5         f.write(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
>
> TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Are you using python2?

Comment: What's your Python version…?

Comment: The builtin function `open()` has a different signature in [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) vs [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using python 2 then try:

```
import codecs
from io import open
with open(filename+'.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for tweet in list_of_tweets:
        print(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
        f.write(tweet.text.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')+'|')
```

The usual open for python2 does not accept encoding.

Comment: Thanks, it's help me for moving from python 3.x to python 2.x